# The use of N-Gram analysis in Sentiment Analysis

Tags: text, analytics, sentiment-analysis, n-gram

How do I use N-Gram Analysis for Sentiment Analysis ?
Once I split a sentence into Uni-Grams, Bi-Grams, Tri-Grams e.t,c.
How do I go forward from there ?

Answer (score 0):

Sentiment analysis often refers to machine learning hence a possible way of doing so is to perform a machine learning algorithm where the attributes are grams.

Still, you can definitely collect some sentimental phrases/words as happy/sad tokens (depends on whether you are using uni-gram or bi-gram...) and simply count the sentences' number of occurrence of the tokens.

Comment: Can I make use of all three, unigram, bigram and trigram analysis. Will it improve my accuracy for the same ?

Comment: It depends. You can use them separately and compare the output but it's not suggested to use them altogether as attributes for single instance as it might rise over-fitting issues...

Comment: If I take just bi gram and tri gram ?

Comment: Say, in n-gram, the system will become more "conservative" as n becomes larger. Hence, as an example, when a sentence is classified as "Happy" using tri-gram, it will be classified as "Happy" as well in bi-gram in most cases. So there is really no need to use them altogether but you may want to use them separately to compare the output and see the trade-off between false-positive and false-negative.

Comment: Thank you. That is highly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Vectorize the X-Grams using bag of words or any other technique and then apply classification algorithm: MaxEnt/SVM/RandomForest. N-Gram don't usually improve the results, in fact using more then 2 grams may even decrease your PR.

Comment: What does vectorizing the X-grams mean ? could you please elaborate ?

Comment: You could use sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer to generate the ngrams:
X = CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2),token_pattern=r'\b\w+\b').fit_transform(corpus).toarray()